# Import and format data inputs with for loop

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I need to import 3 .xlsx files and merge them into 1 DataFrame. I would like to avoid repeating the code by using for loop.

**Original code:**

```
filepath_1 = input('Enter Revenue Month M1 File Path: ')
revenue_month_1 = pd.read_excel(filepath_1)
revenue_month_1 = revenue_month_1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
revenue_month_1['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(revenue_month_1['Month'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna()

filepath_2 = input('Enter Revenue Month M2 File Path: ')
revenue_month_2 = pd.read_excel(filepath_2)
revenue_month_2 = revenue_month_2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
revenue_month_2['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(revenue_month_2['Month'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna()

filepath_3 = input('Enter Revenue Month M3 File Path: ')
revenue_month_3 = pd.read_excel(filepath_3)
revenue_month_3 = revenue_month_3.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
revenue_month_3['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(revenue_month_3['Month'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna()
```

**Code with for loop:**

```
revenue_reports = [
    input('Enter Revenue Month M1 File Path: '),
    input('Enter Revenue Month M2 File Path: '),
    input('Enter Revenue Month M3 File Path: '),
    ]

revenue = []

for revenue_report in revenue_reports:
    revenue = pd.read_excel(revenue_report)
    revenue = revenue.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
    revenue['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(revenue['Month'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna()
    revenue = revenue.append(revenue)
```

Based on this for loop, I get only last month data (M3) from 3 months data imported. Could you help please?

**Update:** Problem was solved. Thanks for the idea from comments below. I've modified a bit. It looks like this:

```
revenue_reports = [
    input('Enter Revenue Month M1 File Path: '),
    input('Enter Revenue Month M2 File Path: '),
    input('Enter Revenue Month M3 File Path: '),
]

revenue = []

x = 1
for revenue_report in revenue_reports:
    revenue_monthly = pd.read_excel(revenue_report)
    revenue_monthly = revenue_monthly.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
    revenue_monthly["M"+str(x)] = pd.to_datetime(revenue_monthly['Month'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna()
    x += 1
    revenue.append(revenue_monthly)
    
revenue = pd.concat(revenue)
```

Comment: Have a closer look on how to use for-loops: I would suggest to define a range (start and end) of your for-loop more properly like ```for k in range(revenue_reports.shape[0])``` and adapt your iterating indices. 

However, the main problem in your code is that you overwrite with each iteration your variable ```revenue``` which always gives you only your last month data (M3)

Comment: Can you put here a sample of your DataFrame output, as screen shoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was fine but the problem was that you were replacing the new value with the previous one that's why you only get the last value of M3
**Try this one**

```
revenue_reports = [
    input('Enter Revenue Month M1 File Path: '),
    input('Enter Revenue Month M2 File Path: '),
    input('Enter Revenue Month M3 File Path: '),
]

revenue = {}
x = 1
for revenue_report in revenue_reports:
    revenue_val = pd.read_excel(revenue_report)
    revenue_val = revenue_val.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
    revenue["M"+x] = pd.to_datetime(revenue_val['Month'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna()
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

May only use a new variable to store All revenue data.

```
revenue_reports = [
    input('Enter Revenue Month M1 File Path: '),
    input('Enter Revenue Month M2 File Path: '),
    input('Enter Revenue Month M3 File Path: '),
    ]

All_revenue =[]

revenue = []

for revenue_report in revenue_reports:
    revenue = pd.read_excel(revenue_report)
    revenue = revenue.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
    revenue['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(revenue['Month'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna()
    All_revenue = All_revenue.append(revenue)
```